# How to increase maxitems in Menu of selected pages

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

In TYPO3 7.x in the Content Element "Special Menus"/"Menu of selected pages" the number of entries is limited to 50. If you add 51 a red exclamation mark pops up. The help (?) shows: "Select a target page or multiple target pages."

I need to add at least 60 pages and have found Bug #59523 at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/59523 related to TYPO3 6.x and a patch to increase the number from 22 in ver 6.x to 50.

I tried to manually implement the same solution in TYPO3 ver 7.x at /sysext/frontend/Configuration/TCA/tt_content.php changing 'maxitems' => '50' to 'maxitems' => '60' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['pages']['config']['maxitems'] = 99;

What can be seen in module Configuration -> TCA ?